# Compiling iptables on OS X fails

Tags: macos, iptables

```
wget http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.6.0.tar.bz2
tar jxvf iptables-1.6.0.tar.bz2
cd iptables-1.6.0
./configure
make
```

During the `make` step, I encounter errors:

```
../include/linux/types.h:4:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
#include <asm/types.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libip4tc.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `iptables` is a Linux firewall product that relies on components in the Linux kernel to function.  I seriously doubt you'll be able to do anything remotely useful with `iptables` on a Mac

Answer (score 2):

IPTables won't work at all on OSX. IPTables uses `netfilter` to tis into the kernel. With OS X, Kernel Extensions are the only way to tie into the kernel. Unless you're using a development version of OS X there's no other way to hook into the TCPIP / Network stacks.

Comment: If you do want to manage the firewall manually, then I suggest you either enable "Parent Controls" in OS X or if you want a more technical approach, then in `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall` you'll find `socketfilterfw ` where you can manually manage the Application Firewall.

Comment: Hope this helps, I've just found a handy post here re: the App Firewall: http://krypted.com/tag/manage-firewall-os-x-command-line/

Comment: You can also use the [OpenBSD "pf" firewall](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) that's already [built into OS X](http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/).